# Website with node.js, hosting architecture decision

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, hosting, vps

I am planning to start my first website. The website is a little HTML5+CSS+JS website with a backend running node.js that serves the data stored on mongodb. I would like to know which one is the best solution regarding mostly the security:

- Web hosting (SSL and cloudflare) + VPS serving on port 3000 (with SSL, cloudflare and node.js with sensible data;users and pass and a local mongodb)
- Everything in the same VPS.
- Any other approach you can give.

The thing is that in the first approach there are two elements in the architecture so if someone wants to hack it i suppose it's more difficult. On the other hand in the second approach if the VPS is hacked everything is hacked and they could access to passwords, mongodb database. I am quite obsessed with security as it is my first website and i don't know what meassures to make to protect my VPS (node.js and mongodb).

Furthermore, i would like to know in terms of efficiency which would be best solution imagine for a 10MB website with 1.000 visits a day.

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question.  The details of which option is more secure has much more to do with the implementation than which of these two choices you use.  One of your two choices isn't innately more secure than the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of how many actual servers you decide to deploy on, I'd strongly suggest not serving your site directly from node.js. Instead, proxy it through a more robust http server such as Apache or Nginx or even lighttpd. For the very simple reason that the http module in node.js was never meant to protect against worms and hacking attempts and various other malware.

I've written web servers from scratch myself and have noticed that in general, you'll get your first hacking attempt within the first hour of putting your server online. You'll get around a dozen or so hacking attempt per day on the slowest days and it goes up from there. These attempts are so common that most server software no longer log them in access logs and simply block them.

From my own personal experience I estimate that around 5% to 10% of my bandwidth is consumed by failed hacking/infection attempts. That is when I'm not being actively attacked.

Security through obscurity is not good security. Especially since node's http module is not very obscure in the first place and someone is bound to find a hackable weakness one of these days.

Apart from security, you also waste fewer CPU cycles ignoring these hacking attempts in Apache or Nginx compared to node.js since you don't need to run any javascript code to handle them.

Comment: Can you offer any references on the vulnerability of node.js to worms/hacking?

Comment: using apache for example instead of node.js http module is it enough to protect against the attacks you mention or is it any other action to take to protect the server?

Comment: @Aitor: Node's CGI support is not really mature enough so you really don't want to use Apache without using node's http module. Also, other languages such as Java, Python, Ruby and Perl have implemented their own lightweight http modules as a way to speed up serving web applications under Apache. Node already has this from day 1. So what you want is to use Apache as a reverse proxy (mod_rewrite) for your node application and configure your firewall so that only Apache is exposed from the outside.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the choice between the two architectures moot. Both architectures are hackable, and your data will be exposed.

If security is paramount, check out [Mylar](http://css.csail.mit.edu/mylar/) - it's a platform that protects data confidentiality **even when an attacker gets full access to servers**. Mylar stores only encrypted data on the server, and decrypts data only in users' browsers.

It runs on top of [Meteor](http://meteor.com), which in turn runs on top of Node.js and uses MongoDB, so if your web app is small, it should be easy to port the code. Meteor also stores passwords using [bcrpyt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/), the best 
password hashing algorithm nowadays.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The question was which of the two choices is more secure.  This is a completely orthogonal recommendation of a different app architecture.

Comment: @jfriend00: sometimes you have to read between the lines and recognize [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I just find it a little odd that knowing absolutely nothing about their app, you jump to recommending a specific security framework.  You don't even know what exactly they're trying to secure.  Basically, it's a bad question that is far too broad to take anything other than wild guesses at (which is what your answer is).  I voted to close the question as too broad.

Comment: I really appreciate Dan's answer, he has given me unknown data which i may  use...i'll give a look at it.

Comment: @jfriend00: Indeed, the question is broad, but it may also be moot (hence my recognizing it as an XY problem). We know some significant bits of their app: Node.js, MongoDB. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: does mylar replace then SSL certificates? As the data is encrypted in the server and decripted in user's browser...

Comment: @Egidi: No it doesn't. Mylar encrypts data fields, that means it won't encrypt meta data like the URL folder you're accessing or the data structure which is transfered or ... You could also decide that you won't encrypt some fields, so that you could do more calculations server-side.